# Why does Jupyter notebook have problems with my code that Pycharm does not?

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm using PyCharm to write my code in and then with Jupyter I have to pass some tests required.

However, the same piece of code that provides a perfect working solution in Pycharm produces a keyerror in Juptyer. Is there any reason why? Numpy seems to be working fine...the problem is with my dictionary. **The following is the error I am getting:**

```
    ipython-input-34-35752ede55c7> in myfunction(input)
         56     mydict = {}
         57     for s in d:
    ---> 58         vals = set(sum(units[s],[]))-{s}
         59         mydict[s] = vals
         60 

    KeyError: 'A1'
```

Edit: in PyCharm you can clearly see A1 definitely exists, yet in jupyter apparently A1 does not, the code is identical in both: (please see image of pycharm debugger)

[image]

Comment: is `units` a dict? looks like it's missing a key that is in `d`, but not `units`. I would need to see your code on Pycharm to dissect more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say without more data/code, but it seems that 'A1' doesn't exist in whatever you're running in Jupyter. Are you absolutely sure that both the data and the code is the same?

Comment: Definitely it is the same, I don't understand though why Jupyter is saying there is a key error when pycharm doesn't seem to have an issue?

Comment: Hmm. That is pretty strange indeed. If possible (and it might not be), I'd suggest posting some data (or dummy data). Would make it a lot easier for people to help and diagnose the problem then.

Answer (score 1):

Key error usually occurs when python is not able to find the key , from your code it is hard to judge without dictionary what the problem may be about how you have mapped the key.